# Where's the option to go directly to inbox on startup in outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Where's the option to go directly to inbox on startup in outlook 2007?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Outlook starts with Outlook Today, Click Customize. The option is there.

Comment: You need to uncheck "start in outlook today" in customize

Answer (score 2):

1. Select Options from the Tools menu.
2. In the Options window click the Other tab.
3. Under General, click the Advanced Options button.
4. In the Advanced Options window, under General Settings, next to Startup in this folder: click the Browse button.
5. Scroll down and click on the plus sign to the left. This will reveal all your folders.
6. Click on the INBOX folder and click OK.
7. Click OK in the Advanced Options window.
8. Click OK in the Options window.

Answer (score 0):

Using the menu's:

- Tools
- Options
- Other
- Advanced Options

Click on Browse and select the folder